# Remove a Google Docs opened in editor

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

I can remove or open the files when they are listed in Google Drive. However, I am not sure that this is the file that I want to remove. I, therefore open it in document editor. Now, I see that I really want to remove it.

But, how do I do that?

If I go back to Google Drive then I am not sure that the "Untiteled document" is the same I just opened and wanted to delete. I therefore open it again and see that I want to delete it. But, I do not see the delete option in the document editor. I therefore close the editor and see "untitle document" in the Google Drive file list. But, I am not sure that this is the file that I want to delete. I therefore open it. In the file editor I see that this is the file that I want to delete. But, I see no option to delete it in the editor. I therefore go back to Google Drive.

How do I stop this hell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-name the document. You should re-name it as "Delete 1" or something similar. That's your first problem. Afterwards you can find the document and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Google Document Editors (Google Docs, Google Sheets, Google Slides) include a "Move to trash" menu option on File menu.